# how to check if SharedPreferences exists for this application in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

my flutter application checks for saved data in `SharedPreferences` every time it starts . to use it later in the application, but when I run the app for the first time in a device, there is saved `SharedPreferences` yet so it gets all the data as `null`. so I want to make sure that it checks if the file itself exists rather than checking for a specific value,

**note:** I'm using this [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) futter package.

here is my code :

```dart
  checkingTheSavedData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String username = prefs.getString('username');
    if (username == null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/main_page');
    }
  }
```

So, for the frist run it does `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/main_page');` but with empty data , after that when i do a real login and the data is already saved , it works fine. any idea how to handle this in a proper way ?

Comment: What you're asking isn't how `shared_preferences` works. What you're actually doing is right. But you say is still goes to the `/main_page` route on first run?

Comment: Yes, first run it goes to the main page and shows all data as null, I think it ignored `    if (username == null) {` as it didn't even find the file in the line`    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();` so I am trying to make it check if the file is already there.

Comment: When debugging, put a breakpoint on the line where you do the check and see what username happens to be

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to check if the key exists yet by using `prefs.containsKey('username')`.

Comment: In case of NULL SAFETY, it is returning NULL, how to check NULL in Null Safety? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You can do the same thing, you just need to force it when you call get - `getString('username')!`

Comment: below solution solved my issue. SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String userData = prefs.getString('userInfo') ?? ""; if (userData == '') {
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          context, LoginScreen.routeName, (r) => false);
    } else {
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          context, HomeScreen.routeName, (r) => false);
    }

Comment: That is not a solution, that is a hacky workaround when not understanding null-safety.

Answer (score 8):

When I use "shared_preferences", I personally use an helper to get and set just like this :

GETTER

```
static Future<String> getUserName() async { 
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('username') ?? '';
}
```

SETTER

```
static Future<String> setUserName(String value) async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.setString('username', value);
}
```

To answer your question, you can't check if the SharedPreferences "file" exist or not. Your method is already correct.

Comment: It works, I have used it in my old projects. Thanks.

Comment: prefs.setString('username', value) returns bool, so i think correct variant is static Future<bool> ...

Answer (score 4):

You are getting empty because you do not have your SharedPreferences KEY yet;
so just put `??` operator and return a value.

```
// Separated shared preferences method is a good call
  Future<bool> isUserLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool(IS_LOGGED_KEY) ?? false;
  }

  // Your logic
  void checkingTheSavedData() {
    isUserLoggedIn().then((isLogged) {
      if (isLogged) {
        // foo
      } else {
        // bar
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Though already you got your answer, nevertheless here I mentioned how I used in my app.

Set the value using this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool("login", true);
```

Check by **containsKey** in Login page

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     if (!prefs.containsKey("login")) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
            return LoginPage();
          },
        ));
     }
```

also check in logout page like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(prefs.containsKey("login")) {
      prefs.remove("login");
      Utils.successToast("Logout successfully");
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
```

Note : you can use whatever you want like 'username' or something else instead on "login"

Comment: Utils is DART 2 INCOMPATIBLE